# Ignoring route parameters in ASP.NET MVC WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-web-api2

I have following web api controller:

```
public class ProductController : ProductControllerBase
{
 public async Task<string> Lookup(string id)
{
   // do lookup
}

public async Task<string> Search(string keywords)
{
    // do search
}
}
```

Sample requests to this api:
http://localhost/api/product/Lookup?provider=amazon&id=B07CSPSMQY
http://localhost/api/product/Lookup?provider=walmart&id=4132478AB
http://localhost/api/product/Lookup?provider=ebay&id=EWRHNFKASDN231

I am fetching provider in base class, because I use it for IoC purposes:

```
public ProductControllerBase()
{
    string provider = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["provider"];
    // resolve search provider depending on parameter
    SetController(provider);
}
```

In my WebApiConfig I have following setup:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    "ProductControllerLookup",
    "api/product/Lookup/{provider}/{id}",
    new
    {

    }
);
```

but once I run URLs above, I keep getting following error:

```
{"Message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'."}
```

What I want is to fetch parameters other than "provider", since I did not want to use it for all methods.

How can I configure this one?

Comment: Did you try adding explicitly attribute Get on the actions? 
` [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
        public async Task<string> Lookup(string id)
        {
            // do lookup
            return "";
        }`

Comment: If I only send id parameter but not provider it hits the method. But if I send both id and provider I got error above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested the code just with adding [HttpGet] attribute, and it seems to be ok, here is my WebApiConfig

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
           "ProductControllerLookup",
           "api/product/Lookup/{provider}/{id}",
            new {}
        );
    }
```

And here is the method:

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    public async Task<string> Lookup(string id)
    {
        var temp = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["provider"];
        // do lookup
        return "";
    }
```

And I'm using your url's and all of them are hitting the method and id and provider are filled.

Comment: OK, thanks for your test. Looks like order of Routes setting was not correct. When I move ProductControllerLookup below to DefaultApi it started to work.

Comment: And yes, seems like adding System.Web.Http.HttpGet worked.